# Why is `23` equals to `10111` in binary

Tags: binary

I've tried to convert 23 to binary and came up with the number `100111` by using the calculation inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86211/333066):

1) Find out the least significant bit:

$$ 23 = \underbrace{(e_n\times 2^n + ... + e_1\times 2^1)}_{22} + 1\times2^0 $$

Which is 1 here.
Continue by shifting to the left by dividing by 2:

```
2) 22/2 = 10 + 1 // next bit is 1
3) 10/2 = 4 + 1 // next bit is 1
4) 4/2 = 2 + 0 // next bit is 0
```

So I'm left with the 2 in decimal, which is 10 in binary. Now I'm writing down the number:

10 plus the the bits from the operations 4, 3, 2, 1 gives me 100111, however, the answer is 10111. Where is my mistake?

Comment: In the next step, you need to divide $2$ by $2$, i.e. `step 5) 2/2 = 0 + 1 // next bit is 1`.

Comment: @achillehui, yes, thanks, I can see that now, or take the required bits from the 4th operation, as shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769870/333066). It seems that fifth operation is not required

Comment: It is not required but it shows why the last piece is $1$ instead of $10$. You have missed a step of dividing by $2$ before you convert the last piece into binary.

Comment: yeah, thanks, added that to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some powers of $2$:

- $2^0 = 1$
- $2^1 = 2$
- $2^2 = 4$
- $2^3 = 8$
- $2^4 = 16$
- $2^5 = 32$

We need to write out $23$, so this is enough powers of $2$.

Start with the highest power of $2$ that is equal to or less than the number.  This is $16$.  So write a $1$ down and subtract it out:  $23-16 = 7$.

The next highest power, $8$, is greater than $7$, so write a zero: $10$.

The next one, $4$, is not greater than $7$, so subtract it out ($7-4=3$) and write a $1$: $101$.

The next one, $2$, is not greater than $3$, so subtract it out ($3-2=1$) and write another $1$: $1011$.

The last one, $1$, is not greater than $1$, so subtract it out ($1-1=0$) and write a $1$: $10111$, and we're done.

Comment: thanks, but this algorithm is not efficient for large integers. I've posted my own answer to the problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769870/333066)

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to write down the number in the following form:

$$ 2\times(2\times(2\times(1\times2^1+0\times2^0)+1\times2^0)+1\times2^0)+1\times2^0 $$

And from this form it's clear that there are only 4 steps needed, so:

```
1) 23 = 22 + 1 // the first bit is 1
2) 22/2 = 10 + 1 // next bit is 1
3) 10/2 = 4 + 1 // next bit is 1
4) 4/2 = 2 + 0 // here, `2 + 0` can be represented as:
```

$$ (1\times2^1+0\times2^0) $$
so, I have two required bits here - `10`, and then I add bits from the previous steps and get the correct result `10111`. It seems that I need to divide by 2 until the quotient has no powers of 2 greater than 1.

It is also possible to have the fifth step in the calculations and then the number would look like this:

$$ 2\times(2\times(2\times(2\times(0\times2^1 + 1\times2^0)+0\times2^0)+1\times2^0)+1\times2^0)+1\times2^0 $$

In this way I need to continue dividing until no powers of 2 remain.