# BCD addition of three digit numbers

Tags: binary

9999+3578

```
 1 0 0 1   1 0 0 1   1 0 0 1   1 0 0 1
+0 0 1 1   0 1 0 1   0 1 1 1   1 0 0 0
```

I don't know how to perform addition for larger numbers.

```
 1 0 0 1    1 0 0 1    1 0 0 1    1 0 0 1
+0 0 1 1    0 1 0 1    0 1 1 1    1 0 0 0
-------------------------------------------
 1 1 0 0     1 1 1 0  1 0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 1
```

This is what i am getting

Comment: thats BCD addition not binary i suppose

Comment: how to perform bcd addition .cant we it treat it as a normal binary addition ?

Comment: but you would get answer like $CF19 (h)$ where h represents hexadecimal

Comment: i think you need to write binary equivalent of 9999 ,3578

Comment: See [Converting decimal(base 10) numbers to binary by repeatedly dividing by 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2)

Comment: teacher told us to write d binary code for each of the digits

Comment: Shortly : if the result (of adding two blocks of 4 bits) is larger than $9$ then add $6$ that's all.

Comment: like i did. if addition is invalid bcd then add 6 to that group

Comment: Not really : $9_{(16)}+9_{(16)}=12_{(16)}$ appears valid but  $6$ has to be added. You should make clear too if you want an implementation or solve this "by hand" (provide the solution of an exercise).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you cant present each digit in binary and sum that up, you need to write down the number as whole in binary, and then sum them up regularly modulo 2.

Comment: Modulo $2$ with *carries*.

Comment: Yeah that's what I obviously meant....

Comment: If only the Question's meaning were so obvious!  It seems to have mutated into, why can't I treat BCD arithmetic as a subset of binary arithmetic, at least for purposes of addition.  The issue comes down to how to perform carries.

Comment: http://www.electrical4u.com/bcd-or-binary-coded-decimal-bcd-conversion-addition-subtraction/

actually the read question is 9999-(-3578) i tried to solve it by using the method given in that website